# Point-to-line-error when joining attributes by location in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, spatial-join, overlapping-features

In QGIS I have several lines with an azimuth attribute. I want to write this attribute to a point layer with `"Join attributes by location"`.

The points lay right on the lines (I used the `"Snap geometries to layer"`-function). Nonetheless, the attribute is only written to points that lay right at the beginning or the end of a line. Points that are in the middle of a line don't get the attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give join attributes by nearest a try ;)

Comment: Are both your layer in the same CRS ?

Comment: Join Attributes by Nearest works! Thanks a lot! A few months ago I did the same procedure already once, and I could swear it worked with Join attributes by location too. Strange...